# Adding user_id into Session mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

I am trying to failing to figure out how to add my user_id from my database to a session like my username is. I would like it so when I log in I can called the session to call the user id posts based on the username used to log in.

How do I do this?

my login php:

```
<?php

session_start();

$connect = mysql_connect( "localhost", "user", "pass") or die('Database could not connect');
$select = mysql_select_db( "database", $connect) or die('Database could not select');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    chckusername($username, $password);
}

function chckusername($username, $password){

    $check = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
    $check_q = mysql_query($check) or die("<div class='loginmsg'>Error on checking Username<div>");

    if (mysql_num_rows($check_q) == 1) {
        chcklogin($username, $password);
    }
    else{
        echo "<div id='loginmsg'>Wrong Username</div>";
    }
}

function chcklogin($username, $password){

    $login = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'  and password='$password' ";
    $login_q = mysql_query($login) or die('Error on checking Username and Password');



print_r($lohin_q);

    if (mysql_num_rows($login_q) == 1){



        header('Location: http://ct6014-williams.studentsites.glos.ac.uk/pages-multi-page/home.php');        
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $userid; //this is where I want to store the user id

    }
    else {
        echo "<div id='loginmsg'>Wrong Password </div>"; 

    }
}
?>
```

on home.php:

```
<?php echo "Your username is " . $_SESSION["username"] . "."; ?>    
     <?php echo "Your id is " . $_SESSION["user_id"] . "."; ?>
```

database names:

`user_id`, `username`, `user_first_name`, `user_last_name`, `user_email`, `password`, `user_reg_date`

**EDIT:**

Ahh, I forgot to say, I have used include( 'login.php' ); which created the session when I logged in as a user. The first username session echos but I cannot seem to figure out hoe to set up the user_id session

Comment: you need to start the session in `home.php` also

Comment: Ahh, I forgot to say, I have used include( 'login.php' ); which created the session when I logged in as a user. The first username session echos but I cannot seem to figure out how to set up the user_id session

Comment: and not use this code if you're live or intend to go live

Comment: I don't :) It is purely for an assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `chcklogin()` function, use [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) function to fetch the row from the result set and assign the required user data to `$_SESSION`. So change your `if (mysql_num_rows($login_q) == 1){ ...` block in the following way,

```
if (mysql_num_rows($login_q) == 1){
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($login_q);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
    header('Location: http://ct6014-williams.studentsites.glos.ac.uk/pages-multi-page/home.php'); 
    exit();
} else {
    echo "<div id='loginmsg'>Wrong Password </div>"; 

}
```

---

**Sidenote:** Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: I'm not too sure on how to do the mysql_fetch_array but I'll give it a go :) Thank you!

Comment: Ah, nevermind :) I got a little confused on the 'In chcklogin()' part but I was having a brain fart and it is all working now.

Comment: Thank you so much x

Comment: @NaomiWilliams You're welcome! Glad I could help. ;-)